# How can I fix resource not found error just after doing Refactor -> Removed Unused Resources?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm using android studio 3.0.1
And facing problem just after doing Remove Unused Resources and the resource not found error is:

```
Error:resource style/Widget.MediaRouter.ChooserText.Primary (aka package-name:style/Widget.MediaRouter.ChooserText.Primary) not found.
Error:resource style/Widget.MediaRouter.ChooserText (aka package-name:style/Widget.MediaRouter.ChooserText) not found.
```

and my Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
targetSdkVersion 27  

dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

How can I fix it,
Thanks

Comment: Update your design support lib  `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'`

Comment: @NileshRathod 27.1.1 is available in my case, but still got an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by adding media router library
`compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'`
Thanks